# master-atul/react-native-exception-handler - does not capture errors in node_modules

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am only able to get this to work for issues at the application level, if an error is thrown from any package in the node_modules, it is not captured.

below is my GlobalErrorHandler, i have imported this into my app.js file at the top of my application so was expecting it to capture any exception in the application.

the expected behaviour would be for the `this.test()` exception to be thrown and from `node_modules/AnotherUIDependency` and captured by the globalErrorHandler

**app.js**

```
...
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from 'MASKED/globalErrorHandler'
...
```

**globalErrorHandler.js**

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native'
import { GlobalStrings } from 'MASKED'
import RNExitApp from 'react-native-exit-app'
import {
  setJSExceptionHandler,
  setNativeExceptionHandler
} from 'react-native-exception-handler'

errorHandler = (e, isFatal) => {
  Alert.alert(
    GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.title,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    errorMessage(e, isFatal, __DEV__),
    [
      {
        text: GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.exit,
        onPress: () => {
          RNExitApp.exitApp()
        }
      }
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )
}

errorMessage = (e, isFatal, isDev) => {
  let val = null
  if (isDev) {
    val =
      GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.error +
      `: ${isFatal ? GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.fatal : ''}` +
      '\n\n' +
      e.name +
      ':' +
      e.message
  } else {
    if (!isFatal) {
      val = GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.exceptionMessage
    } else {
      val = GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.nonFatal + ': ' + e
    }
  }
  return val
}

setJSExceptionHandler(errorHandler, true)
setNativeExceptionHandler(errorString => {
  Alert.alert(
    GlobalStrings.globalErrorHandler.nativeExceptionMessage + ': ' + errorString
  )
})
```

**node_modules/AnotherUIDependency**

```
...
export default class myComponent extends Component {
    render(
        return{
            this.test() // expected globalErrorHandler capture
            ...
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be my usage, however, i found that i had to import my globalErrorHandler at the top of the index file of each package in my project.

I found that even if i implemented it as the docs suggest, it was not truly global as it still would not capture node_module level exceptions.  I would seem that the handler only picks up exceptions where it can follow the imports to the file where the exception occurs.

In my case, we have some weird referencing going on which i think is preventiung this.  I have the same issue even if i use the React-Native `ErrorUtils` global

Answer (score -1):

You're wrong about how to get the module in.

**Usage**
To catch **JS_Exceptions**

```js
import {setJSExceptionHandler, getJSExceptionHandler} from 'react-native-exception-handler';

.
.
// For most use cases:
// registering the error handler (maybe u can do this in the index.android.js or index.ios.js)
setJSExceptionHandler((error, isFatal) => {
  // This is your custom global error handler
  // You do stuff like show an error dialog
  // or hit google analytics to track crashes
  // or hit a custom api to inform the dev team.
});
//=================================================
// ADVANCED use case:
const exceptionhandler = (error, isFatal) => {
  // your error handler function
};
setJSExceptionHandler(exceptionhandler, allowInDevMode);
// - exceptionhandler is the exception handler function
// - allowInDevMode is an optional parameter is a boolean.
//   If set to true the handler to be called in place of RED screen
//   in development mode also.

// getJSExceptionHandler gives the currently set JS exception handler
const currentHandler = getJSExceptionHandler();
```

To catch **Native_Exceptions**

```js
import { setNativeExceptionHandler } from "react-native-exception-handler";

//For most use cases:
setNativeExceptionHandler(exceptionString => {
  // This is your custom global error handler
  // You do stuff likehit google analytics to track crashes.
  // or hit a custom api to inform the dev team.
  //NOTE: alert or showing any UI change via JS
  //WILL NOT WORK in case of NATIVE ERRORS.
});
//====================================================
// ADVANCED use case:
const exceptionhandler = exceptionString => {
  // your exception handler code here
};
setNativeExceptionHandler(
  exceptionhandler,
  forceAppQuit,
  executeDefaultHandler
);
// - exceptionhandler is the exception handler function
// - forceAppQuit is an optional ANDROID specific parameter that defines
//    if the app should be force quit on error.  default value is true.
//    To see usecase check the common issues section.
// - executeDefaultHandler is an optional boolean (both IOS, ANDROID)
//    It executes previous exception handlers if set by some other module.
//    It will come handy when you use any other crash analytics module along with this one
//    Default value is set to false. Set to true if you are using other analytics modules.
```